# Simple Property Management Software

Tags: real-estate, software, landlord

I am a property manager looking over 8 units in a boarding house. I was wondering if anyone knew of any free simple property management software or apps. All I really need to do is keep track of who is currently renting the room, store information about them, record payments each week, and generate a few reports for the landlord (such as the last weeks rent payments).

Does anyone know of anything freeware or affordable thats out there

Comment: this may be a better fit on [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) - but it *sounds* like, for your purposes, a simple spreadsheet would work well for you :)

Comment: I agree with warren - we use spreadsheets to manage our properties.

Comment: Spreadsheets are great until you get to a certain point.  Spreadsheets also won't keep track of communication with tenants, electronic payments, auto late fee assessment and much more.  For these things, as you asked, a property management software solution is best.  There are quite a few nice choices out there, some being more expensive and complicated than others.  We target small to mid-sized portfolio landlords and property managers at [RentPost](https://rentpost.com) with our system, maybe give it a look :)

Answer (score 1):

[Property Manager](http://www.propertyhawk.co.uk/index.php?page=propertyManager) is a free piece of software for exactly this purpose. It's designed for use in the UK, but could be sufficient for non-country-specific details.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the property management software offerings have high monthly minimums.  In some cases the minimums are as high as $200 per month.  [Rentables](https://rentables.com/property-management-software-pricing) offers affordable property management software for just $0.50 per $1000 in monthly rents and no monthly minimum.  It sounds like in your case the monthly fee would be minimal.

Disclosure: I work for Rentables.  We would be happy to assist you in getting set up.

Comment: Jerry - Welcome to Money.SE, and for your honest disclosure. Unfortunately, product recommendations are considered off topic here, and the question itself is likely to be shut down. I'm holding off so the OP can see your answer, but when others vote to close, it won't last long.